# How to group data object to JSon using java

Tags: java, json

How should I create algorithm on creation of following JSON pattern using Java ?

Target JSON pattern is as follows

```
      {
"title":"ABC",
"children":[{
    "title":"ABC_SUK",
    "children":[{
        "title":"ABC_SUK_Block_01",
        "children":[{
            "title":"XXX_201",
        },{
            "title":"XXX_202",  
        }]
    },{
        "title":"ABC_SUK_Block_02",
        "children":[{
            "title":"XXX_203",
        },{
            "title":"XXX_204",  
        }]
    }]
     }]
 }
```

From following table

```
            group | site   | block           |hostname
           _________________________________________
           ABC   | ABC_suk | ABC_SUK_Block_01|XXX_201
           ABC   | ABC_suk | ABC_SUK_Block_01|XXX_202
           ABC   | ABC_suk | ABC_SUK_Block_02|XXX_203
           ABC   | ABC_suk | ABC_SUK_Block_02|XXX_204
```

I am adding 1 object 1 row to `ArrayList<Object>`

Comment: Do you mean `ArrayList` -> `JSon`?

Comment: parse it using Jackson or Gson ...... basically the class structure you create for parsing should be done in a way that it takes grouping into account....

Comment: Yes I mean. Can you guide me. Thank you(johnchen902)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one or more java classes with the structure described above and than you can use a java to json parser (I strongly recommend Jackson) to transform in json the ojbect.
For example:

```
class MyClass {
   String title;
   List<MyClass> children;
   //getters and setters
   //
}
```

You need to load the data from the DB to the class and than use jackson. Read a tutorial, it's very simple: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/